# Chrome instances with different versions

Tags: google-chrome

We have several machines in which Chrome browser is installed.
12.0.742.112
14.0.803.0 dev-m

When we tried to update the browser with updates it doesn't seem to go beyond these revisions. What would be the latest version of Chrome and how do I migrate the version with 12.0.742.112 to the next higher stable version.

Note: Our application doesn't seem to work on 14.0.803.0 and hence would prefer to move to a stable version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything with `dev` in the version number is not stable, you are on the development build.

Try uninstalling Chrome from `Add/Remove programs`/`Programs and features`, then go [here](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=win) and download the latest version of (stable) Chrome.

Comment: Its not clear how certain machines ended up with the 'dev' version though.

Comment: Someone must have manually installed it instead of the release version.